# Defining identity matrix in fortran?

Tags: fortran

I came across this F77 program for writing unit matrix:

```
DO 10 I=1, M
DO 10 J=1, N
    IF(I .EQ. J) THEN
        UNITM(I,J)=1.0D0
    ELSE
        UNITM(I,J)=0.0D0
    END IF
CONTINUE
```

What is the purpose of 10 and .0D0 in the above program?

Comment: 40 years ago, DO syntax required a numeric label to designate loop top and bottom. I suppose this is an example of how to write extremely slow code whilst minimizing use of current syntax.

Comment: Of course, IF THEN ELSE is f77 syntax.  In this case, a good optimizing compiler might be capable of generating fast code by a combination of branch elimination and loop switching, but it's a bit weird to make such a simple task so dependent on specific compiler optimizations.  As for the requirement, assuming UNITM declared DOUBLE PRECISION, at one time the constant had to match data type by using the D syntax, with D0 standing for double precision scaling by 10**0.  For the last 15 years you would write something like 1_wp with wp set to the data type you prefer.

Comment: If you're really traditional, you could write integer,parameter::wp=kind(1d0) but most would recommend selected_real_kind(12) or such, or even wp=real64 if your concern is over storage size.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, the 10 is a line label that is the scope of the do loop. Now we would have an enddo statement. You are missing the 10 above though. The continue line should look like:

```
 10    CONTINUE
```

With modern Fortran we would have 2 enddo statements. With line labels, both do loops can end on the same line.

When Fortran compiles literal numbers, Fortran surmises the number type. A '1' gets compiled as an integer. A '1.0' gets compiled as a single precision real number. Fortran recognized scientific notation so '1.0e3' is 1x10^3 but in single precision!

Substitute the e with a d and Fortran will compile the literal number as double precision! Don't need to have an exponent? Put a 0 for the exponent. So 1.0D0 compiles a 1 as a double precision real number.